# Roll-up summary for counting Activites record

Tags: roll-up-summary

Is it possible to count no. of activities records related to Account.
I want this value on Account page layout.

I have tried using Roll-Up summary but Activity object is not available.

I know it can be achieved using triggers,but is there any way to achieve this with configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of process builder and visual flows to achieve this .please check below link for step by step walkthrough

https://www.xgeek.net/salesforce/create-roll-up-summary-field-to-count-contacts-on-account-with-process-builder-and-flows/

Comment: I have one doubt.Let's say I have to update any of the field of Account when related Task is completed and I have created a Process builder which is working as expected.But,will it work for existing task which is already in completed status.Will it update Account field?

Comment: The example illustrates this .The count will be taken care by builder logic and only on delete you need triggers .Hope that helps .

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this can't be achieved by some standard functionality.You have to choose apex triggers if you want to achieve this.

Comment: Yes..it looks like that way.